# Post Values to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert data in mysql table from fields in a form. however the fields are dynamically allocated, meaning the name is set programmatically. below is a sample of this

```
<?php for ($i=1; $i<=$nombre_parents_arr; $i++): ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo form_label('Nom' . " " . $i) ; ?>
    <?php
        $data = array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'name' => 'nom' . $i,
            'rows' => '3',
            'placeholder' => 'Merci de preciser les infos ici'
        );
    ?>
    <?php echo form_textarea($data); ?>
</div>
```

In my model, i need to get the post and store them in a database. i did the following

```
public function fill_family(){
    $number = $this->input->post('number');
    $data = array(
        'user_id'       =>$this->session->userdata('user_id')
    );
    for($i=1; $i<=$number; $i++){           
        array_push($data, $this->input->post('nom' . $i));          
    } 
    $insert_data = $this->db->insert('temp', $data);
    //var_dump($data);
    return $insert_data;
}
```

When clicking submit on my form, i get the following error in the browser.

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your >MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 1, 2) VALUES ('42', 'samer1', 'samer2', 'samer3')' at line 1
>
> INSERT INTO `temp` (`user_id`, 0, 1, 2) VALUES ('42', 'samer1', 'samer2', >'samer3')

I renamed the columns in my table to user_id, 0, 1 and 2 as it is being generated in the query but it is still not working.

My guess is that it is related to not knowing the correct names of the columns, so i did this in my model inside the for loop

```
'nom' . $i => $this->input->post('nom' . $i);
```

but i kept the same error from mysql. Can anyone provide me with a clue on where my mistake is ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to escape column names starting with number or being numbers with backticks. And what is `>'samer1'`?

Comment: I will look into it thanks. as for the > before samer1, it is just a typo when i formatted the text  in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

**change your query -**

```
$q=0;
foreach($this->input->post('number') as $number) 
{
    if($number!='')
    {
        $data = array(
        "user_id" =>$this->session->userdata('user_id'),
        'nom' . $q =>$this->input->post('value_of_html_name_attribute ')[$q],
        'nom' . $q =>input->post('value_of_html_name_attribute ')[$q],
        'nom' . $q =>input->post('value_of_html_name_attribute ')[$q],
        );

        $this->db->insert('temp',$data);
    }

    $q++;   
}
```

hope this will work !

Comment: I am trying this. i saw the edits you made. I am getting an error on the foreach arguments. i will let you know when i sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO temp (user_id, 0, 1, 2) VALUES ('42', 'samer1', 'samer2', >'samer3')`

If you're using column names that consist solely of numbers, they must be quoted with backticks.

```
INSERT INTO temp (user_id, `0`, `1`, `2`) VALUES ('42', 'samer1', 'samer2', 'samer3')`
```

**UPDATE**

See [MySQL Identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html): "Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits."